# How to design JSF entry point page with conditional navigation logic before the page displays?

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, redirect

The entry point to my JSF application is `EntryPoint.jsp`.  We are using JSF 1.2.  The user may call `EntryPoint.jsp` with a number of different URL parameters.  I woud like to parse these parameters, load up a session bean with some state, do all this before the page loads and either continue processing/display `EntryPoint.jsp` or foward/redirect to another page in the application.  Can anyone recommend the best design for this?

I've tried in my EntryPoint.java backing bean (exception handling removed):

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    companyName = request.getParameter("companyCode");
    //process parameters...
    if (someCondition) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("/other.jsp");
        return;
    }
 }
```

but I get an `IllegalStateException: Response already committed`.

I've also tried

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/other.jsp");
```

but also get an IllegalStateException (with no message).  Clearly this isn't the appropiate way or place to do this.  Can anyone recommend a better way to achieve what I am looking for?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386174/jsf-redirect-on-page-load) seems to suggest a servlet filter might be a good choice.  If so, would the session scope JSF backing bean be available in the servlet filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed not going to work for JSF 1.x. As you found in the other question, a `Filter` is indeed a more appropriate place for this job. This answer has not been changed since then. A session scoped JSF managed bean is stored in the `HttpSession` with the managed bean name as session attribute name. So yes, it's accessible in the `Filter`. Even more, the `Filter` could precreate it and put it in the session. JSF will then use it instead of autocreating one.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.  Your last sentance in particular answers my niggling question (i.e. would the session bean be available prior to any JSF framework interactions).

Comment: You're welcome. You only need to keep in mind that `@EJB`, `@PostConstruct` and likes won't be injected/invoked. But I don't think that this is a problem as you *usually* don't see it on a session scoped bean.